# WELD-001308 with empty qualifieirs

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, wildfly-10, weld

I have this error in my application, but it doesn't say much about the source of error.

```
ERROR [stderr] Exception in thread java.lang.RuntimeException: 
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: WELD-001308: 
Unable to resolve any beans for Type: interface 
org.jboss.weld.context.http.HttpSessionContext; Qualifiers: []
```

In what scenarios this error might occur?

- Java - 8
- Wildfly 10.1.0
- Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Weld cannot find one of its very own beans. Sounds like classpath pollution with multiple different versioned Weld libraries. You'd better create a minimal reproducer project from scratch which demonstrates this problem. Remember that WildFly already ships with its own Weld library.

Comment: Also, are you seeing this from an injection point in your own code?  Perhaps you could include some of your start up logs as well.

Comment: I have not included any weld libraries, I'm using Widlfly's shipped libraries. I have upgraded to widlfly 11.0.0 and it seems the problem is gone.